# What I can use to replace black beer on roast recipe?

Tags: substitutions, beef, alcohol, beer, roast-beef

I have a "basic" recipe for roast beef that uses 1 bottle of black beer as an ingredient.

I am looking for a non-alcoholic ingredient to replace it because my parents don't drink alcohol and I usually don't have alcohol on hand.

Answer (score 5):

Non-alcoholic beer makes sense. If you can't find any you could simmer alcoholic beer for about 3 hours, which should remove the vast majority of the alcohol. You might need to add a little water afterwards if it has reduced too much.

Answer (score 3):

Black Beer is not beer as you would know it! It is a thick concentrated malt liquor. The best substitute would be a non-alcoholic dark malt liquor, or some malt extract.

http://www.drinksdirect.co.uk/acatalog/Mathers_Black_Beer.html

Comment: It is interesting to know where the recipe comes from; regionally, "black beer" *is* used for specific types of dark beer. We may have found a new candidate for the regional terms CW.

Answer (score 3):

Try some variety of Malta beverage.  Malta is a hopped, malt soda/pop.  Essentially it's unfermented and carbonated beer.  Especially if black beer is exceptionally malty and sweet, Malta would be a good non-alcoholic substitute.  If your recipe has some sweet aspect elsewhere you might cut back on that if Malta is too sweet.